# Does php internal server read .htaccess configuration?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a .htaccess with some rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)\.page$ index.php?module=$1 [L]
```

When I launch php server with `php -S 127.0.0.1:80` in current dir, http://127.0.0.1/home.page page is not found on my server.
So I can understand that php internal server does not read RewriteRule's at least.
Is it true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is true. .htaccess is used and processed by Apache. Apache handles the requests. It just loads PHP as a helper to parse and execute PHP files. When PHP is started as a stand-alone server, it won't use those configurations.

You can check out [this GitHub project](https://github.com/jaytaph/HTRouter) for an .htaccess parser that can be used with PHP's built in server. Note though, that this project is an undefined state, somewhere between 'alpha' and 'abandoned'. [This blog post](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/php-5-4-built-in-webserver) links to that project too, and provides a little more context.

As a side note, PHP's internal server is not to be used as a production server. It doesn't have the power, flexibility, stability and security of a full fledged server like Apache or Nginx.